# How can I define a NSMenuItem without having to define a keyEquivalent for it?

Tags: swift, cocoa

Currently I am using this code for defining my NSMenuItem:

```
let showWindow1 = NSMenuItem(title: "Show Window 1", action: #selector(showWindow1), keyEquivalent: "1")
```

This code works but as you can see it needs a keyEquivalent, in my app there is some actions that they do not need a keyEquivalent like Xcode app:

[image]

So I tried this below code for solving my problem:

```
let showWindow1 = NSMenuItem()
showWindow1.title = "Show Window 1"
```

This code Adds an item but it is grayout and it is not clickable any more from other side I do not know the way to assign the selector for it without having to give keyEquivalent for it.

Comment: Just leave the keyEquivalent blank, ie keyEquivalent:@""  . Assign selector as usual.  This works for programmatic menu system.  Not sure about nibs.

Comment: For a menu item to be "enabled" it must have an action, and either a target or the first responder needs to respond to action and optional menu validation must allow the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass an empty string instead of a key:

```
let showWindow1 = NSMenuItem(title: "Show Window 1", action: #selector(showWindow1), keyEquivalent: "")
```